Doubling dimension of a hypercube in $\mathbb R^d$
For a metric space $X$, the doubling constant $\Delta$ of $X$ is defined to be the smallest integer such that every ball of arbitrary radius $r$ can be covered by at most $\Delta$ balls of radius $r/2$. The doubling dimension of $X$ is defined to be $\dim(X):=\log_2 \Delta$.
Let $H$ be a unit hypercube sitting in $\mathbb R^d$. What is $\dim(H)$?
(In particular I mean $H\cong S^d$, and I regard $H$ as a metric space with the induced metric)
I have managed to get some upper bounds for $\dim(H)$:
Since $H \subset \mathbb R^d$ and $\dim(\mathbb R^d) \leq C d$ for some universal constant $C$ (cf. this post), then since doubling dimension is preserved for subsets up to a factor of $2$, we have $\dim (H) \leq 2 \dim(\mathbb R^d) \leq 2Cd$.
Another upper bound can be obtained as follows:
Note that $H$ is the union of $2d$ faces $F_1, \dots F_{2d}$, each of which are a subset of some $(d-1)$-dimensional affine space. Therefore $\dim(F_i) \leq C(d-1)$ for each face $F_i$. By Lemma 3 of this paper, therefore $\dim (H) \leq C(d-1) + \log(2d)$.
I suspect that the doubling dimension can be reduced further to $\dim(H) \leq C'(d-1)$ for some universal constant $C'$, but I haven't figured out a direct argument yet.
